# Looping through list in pairs or more

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, for-loop

Simplest way to iterate in pairs or more in python over a single list?

```
list1=['Hello ','World','.','I ','heart ','python']
```

Something like this:

```
for x,y,z in list1:
    print x,y,z
```

What I would like to get as a result:

> Hello World.
>
> I heart python

I know I can do it like this but I would like to know if there is something that doesn't require index counting. Preferably using a for loop.

```
index=0
while index<len(list1):
     print list1[index],list1[index+1],list1[index+2]
     index+=3
```

Comment: I suppose it is. I didn't think to add the word 'chunk'to my search so that question never came up.

Comment: Yes, perhaps not the most obvious word to look for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use zip to turn your list into a list of tuples, and then u can iterate over that:

```
list1 = zip(list1[0::2], list1[1::2])
for elem1, elem2 in list1:
   print elem1, elem2
```

Comment: And if there is an odd number of items in the list, you lose the last item.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how more or less pythonic this is but

```
for x, y, z in zip(list1[::3],list1[1::3], list1[2::3]):
  print x+y+z
```